# Issue with precedence and ++ and * unary operators in C

Tags: c, pointers, operators, operator-precedence, unary-operator

My question is not long, but it's puzzling for me. I'm one of those people who (and I think rightfully so) want to know every single rule of the languages they learn. I want to know why the language does what it does.

So, why does `++*i` increment the value of `*i`, rather than the `i` pointer? The preincrement operator has a higher precedence than the indirection operator. It seems like a common sense thing, but again, I must know exactly why. Please provide references if you can.

Answer (score 5):

It cannot be parsed as `*(++i)`, can it?

By the way, `*` and prefix `++` have **the same precedence**, and right-to-left associativity.

Comment: That makes sense. I just verified my manual has a typo, it says that ++ is higher than *.

Comment: Postfix ++ (post-increment) is higher, prefix ++ (pre-increment) is not.

Answer (score 3):

Prefix `++` has same precedence as unary `*` while postfix `++` hsa higher precedence than unary `*` operator.
In case of `++ *i` compiler interpret it as

```
++ (*i);
```

That means, dereference `i`, use it, increment the dereferenced value without changing the value of pointer.

Comment: C manuals often state that postfix and prefix operators have the same precedence, but the associativity makes it pretty much irrelevant about who's right, it seems.